# Create a view on two tables where data in one table matches the row number of second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables T1 and T2.T1 contains five columns and it has data which points to the rows in table t2(T2 has just one column).How do I create a view which shows columns from T1 and data from T2.

e.g

T1

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
2   4   3   1   5
```

T2

```
 C6 
 1001
 1002
 1003
 1004
 1005
```

I want to create a view which is like:

V1

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
1002    1004    1003    1001    1005
```

Note:There are no common columns in both tables.

Comment: so how will you know that `2` will match with `1002`?

Comment: It looks like SELECT C1=C1+1000, C2=C2+1000, C3=C3+1000, C4=C4+1000, C5=C5+1000 FROM T1 produces the desired result.

Comment: @JW:The data in T1 points to row number of table T2.therefore,value 2 in T1 means ,it point to row number 2 of table T2 i.e 1002-NSB

Comment: @PG:Please read the question again(no offence)..Also the values in both tables are not matching..this is just an example..Basically, T1 can contain any value and it points to that row number in table t2..

Comment: Which flavour of database are you using?  Or are you one of those people who thing [sql] means [sql-server]?

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

> "T2 has just one column"

This means `select * from t2` can return the rows in any order, because you have no sort criterion.  Your question presupposes that `2` will always indicate the second row in the T2 table but that is not the case.